# How do I get the signature image from a smartcard with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, itext, x509certificate

I'm developing a C# application to certify pdf documents. I've got the certification process done but now I need to take the signature image stored in a smartcard and place it in the given PDF file.
The code used to get the certificates is this:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection col = st.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 card = null;
        X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, "Certificates", "Select one to sign", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
        if (sel.Count > 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2Enumerator en = sel.GetEnumerator();
            en.MoveNext();
            card = en.Current;
        }
        st.Close();
        return card;
    }
```

And then I apply the chosen one to the Document here:

```
            if(card == null)
            {
            ChooseCertified:
                card = GetCertificate();

                if (card == null)
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Unable to identify certificates" +
                                           Environment.NewLine + "Would you like to try again?", "Certification error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (result.CompareTo(DialogResult.Retry) == 0)
                        goto ChooseCertified;
                    else
                        return 1;
                }
            }

            X509CertificateParser cp = new X509CertificateParser(card.RawData);
            org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Certificate[] chain = new org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate() };

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(original_pdf_file);

            PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(result_pdf_file, FileMode.Create), '\0', null, true);

            PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.SignatureAppearance;

            sap.Layer2Text = "Document signed by " + Environment.NewLine +
                                card.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false) + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Date: " + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Reason: " + REASON;        
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rct = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
            float lowerx = 0, upperx = 0, lowery = 0, uppery = 0;
            if (valign == "top")
            {
                lowery = (rct.Height - height) - vert_margin;
                uppery = rct.Height - vert_margin;
            }
            else
            {
                lowery = vert_margin;
                uppery = vert_margin + height;
            }
            if (halign == "left")
            {
                lowerx = hor_margin;
                upperx = hor_margin + width;
            }
            else
            {
                lowerx = (rct.Width - width) - hor_margin;
                upperx = rct.Width - hor_margin;
            }
            sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(lowerx, lowery, upperx, uppery),1, null);
            sap.SignDate = date;
            sap.SetCrypto(null, chain, null, null);
            sap.Reason = REASON;
            sap.Location = LOCATION;
            iTextSharp.text.Font f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.HELVETICA, 7, 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
            f.SetStyle("Bold");
            sap.Layer2Font = f;
            sap.Acro6Layers = true;

            PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
            dic.Date = new PdfDate(date);
            dic.Name = PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields(chain[0]).GetField("CN");
            dic.Reason = REASON;
            dic.Location = LOCATION;
            sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
            int csize = 4000;
            Hashtable exc = new Hashtable();
            exc[PdfName.CONTENTS] = csize * 2 + 2;
            sap.PreClose(exc);

            HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            Stream s = sap.RangeStream;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
            while ((read = s.Read(buff, 0, 8192)) > 0)
            {
                sha.TransformBlock(buff, 0, read, buff, 0);
            }
            sha.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, 0);

            byte[] pk = SignMsg(sha.Hash, card, false);

            byte[] outc = new byte[csize];

            PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();

            Array.Copy(pk, 0, outc, 0, pk.Length);

            dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(outc).SetHexWriting(true));
            sap.Close(dic2);
```

So what i need now is a way to get the signature image that is store on the card and after a lot of google searching i found nothing regarding this matter. I would really aprecciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You say it is stored on the card. How is that done? Is it stored in some dedicated part of the card layout? Or is it stored in the certificate? In the latter case please supply a sample of such a certificate with an image attribute for reference.

Comment: I believe it is but i'm currently awaiting feedback on the matter.

Comment: Please read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures It won't give you a direct answer because it only discusses the Belgian eID smartcard, but that's where you should start. The Belgian eID has a private key that can be used for signing; so should your card. The Belgian eID doesn't contain an image with a signature, but it contains a picture of the owner of the card. The book I refer to explains how to extract that image. In another chapter, you'll discover how to use an image for a signature widget.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: the signature you're creating isn't future-proof! PKCS7_SHA1? Bad idea! You should upgrade to the latest iText version.

Comment: hey thanks. ill take a look at the book and see if it helps! :) what kind of encription would you advise?

Comment: @Ninglin It's not merely about some encryption algorithm, it's about the signature architecture, in the context of PDF signatures known as **SubFilter**. You are using the subfilter **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** but according to [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) *the format for encoding signature values should be **adbe.pkcs7.detached**,* which implicitly made **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** deprecated already in 2008.

Comment: yes, now that i've read the paper i know that :) but thanks anyway! and congratz to @BrunoLowagie for the excelent work ;) i resolved the issue in the meanwhile and with the aid of that paper :D