# Thumbnail Image for Certificate / Smart Card Log on

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, x509certificate2

I'm working on a log on prompt where users sign certificates to log on the system, but in my log on prompt I would like to display the thumbnail images "from the certificates", but where are they? Are they generated?

Windows does the same when using smart cards as log on - displaying a nice square thumbnail image with either logo or some text on it.

Here is my (standard) code for reading certificates with type of X509Certificate2:

```
 var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
 certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 var certificates = certificateStore.Certificates;
 certificateStore.Close();
```

I've searched the web several times and found only this similar and unanswered [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892738/how-do-i-get-the-signature-image-from-a-smartcard-with-c)

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Most probably you talk about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but since I am not sure, this is a comment rather than the answer.

Comment: the X509Certificate2UI class does for some vierd reason not exist in my 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates , which msdn says. otherwise I've would have tested it. But thanks anyway

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Security`?

Comment: Yes. Tried both 
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
and
using System.Security;
and both separately.

Comment: No, it's not about `using` but about adding a reference.

Comment: Ok now I got 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(
            certificates[1]);
working, but all it does is what MMC.exe does when opening a certificate, which is displaying a form with issuer, issued to, valid to date etc.

Comment: on the other hand:

System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(selection, "title", "message", flag);

does close to what I want, but no chance for adding extra buttons etc.

Comment: Yep, no chance. If you want a custom ui, you'd have to do it by yourself.